# Two tables join by number interval

Tags: sql, database, join

Hello I have two SQL tables, first look like this:

```
| id | position | name  |
|----|----------|-------|
| 1  | 553      | John  |
| 2  | 876      | James |
| 3  | 999      | Jack  |
```

And second like this:

```
| id | class  | interval_start | interval_end |
|----|--------|----------------|--------------|
| 1  | class1 | 500            | 580          |
| 2  | class2 | 600            | 700          |
| 3  | class3 | 900            | 1200         |
```

And I would like to add class from second table to first table based on interval (if t1.position is bigger than start and smaller than end - add another column with class)
So result should be:

```
| id | position | name  | class  |
|----|----------|-------|--------|
| 1  | 553      | John  | class1 |
| 2  | 876      | James |        |
| 3  | 999      | Jack  | class3 |
```

I am not sure how to do that, because I have very large tables (millions of rows). I can also download the data and process it manually in Python.

Which way do you think will be optimal for this task?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I have posted the answer as generic SQL as you didn't mention the specific database, you can try it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `left join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.class
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.position between t2.interval_start and t2.interval_end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below SQL, it will fulfill your requirement.

```
select  t1.id,
        t1.position,
        t1.name,
        t2.class
from table1 t1
 left join table2 t2
   on (t1.id = t2.id
    and t1.position between t2.interval_start and t2.interval_end
       );
```

Output:

```
+------+----------+-------+--------+
| id   | position | name  | class  |
+------+----------+-------+--------+
|    1 |      553 | John  | class1 |
|    3 |      999 | Jack  | class3 |
|    2 |      876 | James | NULL   |
+------+----------+-------+--------+
```